# Increasing partition size with unallocated space to the left

Tags: partitioning, unallocated

I have 100MB unallocated at the beginning of my hard drive. How can I merge them to another partition?

[image]

Gparted only allows me to increase space if it is in the right. If I try to increase the partition to the left, it tells me that moving a partition might cause my operating system to fail to boot.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to extend `/dev/sda3`?

Comment: I want to remove the unallocated space at the beginning, it doesn't matter if I extend /dev/sda3 or /dev/sda2.

Comment: That would be a warning, and does not prevent you from proceeding.  It also will take a long time since the entire existing partition has to be moved first, during which any interruption will trash your data, so it is advised against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the partition to the right, then extend it into the free space, in two steps (move -> apply changes -> extend -> apply changes)

Yes, there can be data loss or problems if you more or resize partitions, so back up any data first.

if you can not boot, fix it with boot repair - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

You can run boot repair from a live CD.

Comment: The problem is that gparted doesn't allow me to move it to the right, at least I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You may not be able to move it any further. You may have to resize it then move it (copy-paste) and resize it again.

Comment: Took a long time but it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Since the free space is to the left, moving to the right is not an option.

Comment: It would be nice if gparted would figure this sort of thing out on it's own, but alas ...

Comment: It is important to stress, that the target partition *must not be mounted*. If mounted, the gparted's interface will fail to show you the possibility of moving to the left *without any explanation why it can't*.

Comment: booting from a live cd is necessary not only to repair possible errors, but also to proceed with the resizing: because that target partition is the one where the OS is installed and that should not be mounted